# Multiple Services Specified by docker-compose.yml on a Single Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gcloud

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which specifies *two* services `AAA` and `BBB` as follows,

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  AAA:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: .
    image: AAA
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR=1
    volumes:
      - ./data:/root/data
    ports:
      - 5900:5900
    restart: on-failure
  
  BBB:
    image: BBB
    build: ./service_directory
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    volumes:
      - ./data:/root/data
    ports:
      - 5901:5901
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - AAA
```

And here's my directory structure:

```
project
|  docker-compose.yml
|  Dockerfile
|
|--service_directory
   |
   |--Dockerfile
```

I'm led to believe that google cloud lacks direct `docker-compose` support, and one must translate the docker compose script into a `cloudbuild.yaml` file.

How should one specify the multiple services, the `environment`, `ports`, `volumes` information and the dependency of `BBB` on `AAA` in a `cloudbuild.yaml` file such that both services build on a single compute engine VM instance, as one would otherwise expect from running the `docker compose up` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Compute Engine VMs (running Linux) are functionally equivalent to any other Linux machine and you can run Docker Compose as you would elsewhere.

You may need to install Docker and Docker Compose as you would on any Linux host.

Google [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build) provides different functionality to Docker Compose; the two are not equivalent. Cloud Build is a cloud-based pipeline tool that is mostly used (but is not limited) to define the steps needed to create container images.